# How to pass and editing data frame as an argument in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to split an array in a data-frame column and append the individual entries to a new data frame.

I managed to write a function that seems to be able to iterate over the individual entries. But when I try to append them to another data frame, the data frame stays empty.

Can I even edit a data frame from within a function?

```
import pandas as pd

# Original data frame
series1 = pd.Series([['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit'], ['frog', 'moose', 'fly']])
oldDF = pd.DataFrame(series1)

# New data frame where I want to populate all values in the old
series2 = pd.Series([])
newDF = pd.DataFrame(series2)

# Define function to iterate over each array 
def appendItems(x, df):
  for item in x:
    for i in item: 
      # Trying to append entries to new dataframe
      df.append(pd.Series([i]), ignore_index=True)
      print(pd.Series([i]))

# Apply above function to dataframe
oldDF.apply(appendItems,args=[newDF])

# Result-> empty data frame :-(
print("Checking result")
newDF.head()
```

Comment: I was hoping to get a column with one animal per cell: cat, dog, rabbit etc. So a data frame with 6 rows instead of two.

Comment: try `pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(oldDF[0]))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are facing with your `appendItems` function is that it uses `df.append()` which is creating a copy and does not modify in place.
`df.append()` uses `pd.concat()` under the hood.
if you really want to use your appendItems function, you should use `df.loc[]` to modify directly df and not a copy.
Here is an example:

```
def appendItems(x, df):
    for i, item in enumerate(pd.np.hstack(x.values.tolist())):
        df.loc[i, 0] = item
```

(`np.hstack` is just used to flatten the nested list of values)

links:
[pd.DataFrame.append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

[pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)

[np.hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using **`numpy.concatenate`**

```
import numpy as np

pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(oldDF[0]))
```

[output]

```
        0
0     cat
1     dog
2  rabbit
3    frog
4   moose
5     fly
```